# Text is jumping to left in css card flip on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have this CSS card flip I am working on. I have it working perfectly on hover. I added some jquery to allow for a flip on click but now anything I lay out inside the card shifts to the left right before the card flips. Not sure what I can do to fix it. I've tried a bunch of things but I am not really sure what is causing it. I am attaching a codepen.

Sorry for the sloppy paste of my code below. SO forces you to post code w your pen. Looking at the pen is easier to look at.

Here is my code followed by a pen:

```
<div class="container2">
  <div class="card2">

    <div class="face front">
      <img width="300px" src="logo.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="face back">
      <h3>Web Ascender</h3>
      <p>Web Ascender is an innovation services company that truly cares about your happiness and the success of your project. We are leaders in web development, mobile applications and internet marketing, but our team doesn't just make beautiful digital products. We successfully solve real problems for people and businesses.</p>
      <a href="/Contact" class="btn btn-block btn-outline">Learn More &rsaquo;</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    .container2{
  width:400px;height:300px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.card2{
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.card2 h3{color:#fff;}
.card2 p{color:#fff;font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;font-weight:300;}


.front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/*.card2:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card2:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}*/

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; backface-visibility: hidden; transition: 0.5s;
}
.face.front{
  background:#000;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333;
}
.card2 a.btn.btn-block{display:block;}
.card2 a.btn.btn-outline{background:transparent;border:1px solid #fff;border-radius:3px;padding:10px;color:#fff;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;}
.card2 a.btn.btn-outline:hover{background:#222;border:1px solid transparent;}

$(document).ready(function() {

$( ".card2" ).click(function() {
$('.face').toggleClass('front');
$('.face').toggleClass('back');

});

});
```

http://codepen.io/JohnDangerous/pen/ZpVqOQ

Comment: So the above is what I tried in order to get the css to fire on click. I updated the pen with the hover classes because I could not get all the .face.front and the .face.back classes to fire along with the .front and .back classes.

Answer (score 2):

Update

```
.face.back {
     text-align: left;
}
```

to

```
.face.back {
     text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Shoot I thought I had it but there is still some issue. The reason the text was jumping was because these classes were not firing off:

Comment: .face.front{
    background:#000;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .face.back {
    display: block;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: red;
    }

Comment: Sorry that css is no help. I updated the pen with the expected result I would like to have on a jquery click